# Make java ignore calls to X11

Tags: java, swing, headless

Is there any way I could make java ignore any calls in code to the X11 system? I'm running an application on a server machine, which has no window manager. When I run this app I get the java.awt.HeadlessException. I have already tried to set -Djava.awt.headless=true / System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", true). No luck.

Do I really have to manually remove all code lines where the interaction with graphical system is made or there is a more elegant way? Thx.

Comment: You could install a virtual window manager like http://www.tightvnc.com/. Which would circumvent the problems.

Comment: I did. Then I set up DISPLAY to match the VNC desktop, but I still get the java.awt.HeadlessException.

Comment: This might sound silly, but what version of JVM are you using. It appears that up until (and including some) version 1.4 there was a bug on the Sun/Oracle jdk for this: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4281163. Also fi you're using another jdk, look that it itself doesn't still have this bug (apparently the Apple JDK had thing bug for a long long time)

Comment: java.awt.headless must be false if you have a display. You get the headless exception when headless=true and some call to a gui is made

Comment: Did you install VNC on the headless, remote server, start it on the server, and then connect to it from your VNC client?

Comment: @trashgod yes, i'm set it to false when testing that solution;

Comment: @Andrei Bodnarescu: i'm using jre1.6 from sun;

Comment: @Udo Fholl: my os is slackware 13.37 64-bit;

Comment: alternatives --config java does work in your linux?

Comment: I don't have that in my distro + wouldn't like to have a sys dependant solution.

Comment: @Andrei Bodnarescu your comment was helpful. It was indeed a bug. I forgot to purge OpenJdk. Removing it did the trick, since "java" link was referring to a wrong binary.

Answer (score 0):

Use java in headless mode
[Java headless mode](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/)

Comment: You can't instantiate a top-level container in headless mode.

Comment: So the only solution is to manually locate all places where X11 calls are made and comment them?

Comment: Don't know about slackware, but VNC works on many platforms and has for a [while](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1012&hilit=X11+DISPLAY+BufferedImage).